# Funcion para obtener propiedades de un objeto por su id

Tags: javascript, array, api, poo

Tengo este array de objetos y quiero crear una funcion para obtener la info de la propiedad por su id, si ingreso el numero del id que me traigo la info de ese objeto. no se como formularlo

````
let foo = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops',
     
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Mens Casual Premium Slim Fit T-Shirts ',
      
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Mens Cotton Jacket',
      
    }
   ]


function searchById(id){
for (let i = 0; i< foo.length; i++){
    if(foo[1].id == id){
        console.log(id)
    }
}
}

searchById(1)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te refieres a esto:

```javascript
function searchById(id) {
  for (let i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    if (foo[i].id == id) {
      console.log(id)
      console.log(foo[i].title)
    }
  }
}
```

Cambios:

1. He cambiado `foo[1].id` por `foo[i].id` para que en cada ciclo me saque sus datos correctamente
2. He agregado un `console.log(foo[i].title)` para que veas la sintaxis con la que puedes acceder a esa propiedad **title** del objeto iterado.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar el método [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) que sirve para devolver el primer valor de un array que cumpla con una función.

Te quedaría algo así:

```
function searchById(id) {
  const found = foo.find(elem => elem.id == id)

  console.log(found.title)
}
```